# what's number anagram which are palindromes in string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, palindrome, anagram

What is the number of anagrams which are palindromes in a string?
Example : string  = "aaabbbb";
Possible anagram's which are palindromes "abbabba" , "bbaaabb" and "bababab".
The problem here is the time, i have string of size 10^9.
here's my final code can anybody tell me what's the wrong with it ?

Comment: Uhm, three? Seriously, you need to explain a little more "what you have done, and what you are struggling with".

Comment: ok, giving a string what's the number of permutation that's palindrome ?

Comment: Show us what you've done, and tell us what problems you've run into. We want to see some code.

Comment: Here's the code :#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
bool is_palindrome (string s){
 string ss = s;
 reverse(ss.begin(),ss.end());
 return(ss == s);
}
int main() {
 string s = "aaabbbb";
 long long res = 0;
 sort(s.begin(),s.end());
 do{
  if(is_palindrome(s)){
   cout << s <<endl;
   res ++;
  }
 }while (next_permutation(s.begin(),s.end()));
 cout << res << endl;
 return 0;
} what if the size of the string is 10^9 ?

Comment: Sorry, this is better calculation: 7!/(3!*4!)=5040/144=35 is number of words. Check every of 35 words is it palindrome!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every letter in your input string has to appear in an even amount, execpt one letter can appear in an odd amount. This letter has a fixed position in the palindron. It has to be exactly in the middle. Lets say the amounts of the letter a,b,c,... are #a, #b, #c, ...

You only care about half of those letters, because in an palindron, the second half depands of the first half. So we only use half of the letters:

[image]

I used the floor function, so I calculate the letter, which appears in an odd amount, correct.

So how many permutations are in the first half? This is a case of distinct permutation, so we get

[image]

possibilities.

---

For your example: 
string = "aaabbbb";

We get: #a=3, #b=4. Therefore

[image]

We get 3 palindroms, these are "abbabba" , "bbaaabb" and "bababab", like you posted.

---

So, if you have a very large string:

1. Count the amounts of each letter
2. Check, if there is only 1 letter that appears in an odd amount. It there are more, you can't create palindroms.
3. Use the formular to calculate the number of different palindroms.

Comment: Thank you :) 
I think i get it :))

Comment: i think i have another problem that's if the string not sorting so i will not get all permutation "like your algorithm" ?

Comment: That's no problem, just write a good counting function. I suggest: iterate through your input string and save the letters, which have appeared already. You can do this, by having two arrays, one, which contains the letters (a char array), and one, which contains the amount of this letter (int array). If a new letter appears, just add the letter in the first one and a 1 in the second one, if a already known letter appears, just increase the amount in the int array.

Answer (score 0):

Since each side of the anagram must be a mirror image of the other, the number of anagrams we care about is basically just the number of anagrams we can form on one side, so:

1. group the characters in the string so identical characters are together (e.g., by sorting).
2. Check for an odd number of more than one character (of so, # anagrams = 0).
3. Take half the characters of each group of identical (truncating in the case of odd number).
4. Compute the number of unique permutations of those characters.

Comment: The problem here is the time to compute the number of unique permutations of those characters, the max size of string is 10^5 
and what if the max size was 10^9 ?

Comment: "The problem here is the time to compute the number of unique permutations" Calculating number of unique permutations is not problem, harder problem is to generate all permutations :)

Comment: Yup :) 
How i can solve this problem ?

Comment: Given N items with M identical, the number of unique permutations is N!  / M!.

Comment: ok,right now i know the number of unique permutations how i can get the number of palindromes of this unique permutations ?

Comment: @Ahmed_Mohsen: The number of unique permutations and number of palindromes is the same (assuming you divided each group by 2, as in the answer above).

Comment: string s = "aaabbbb" the answer is 3. but using your algorithm the answer will be 7! / 2! = 1260 / 2 = 630 ..

Comment: @Ahmed_Mohsen: You seem to have skipped step 3.

Comment: I think i have another problem that's if the string not sorting so i will not get all permutation ?

Comment: As noted, sorting is just a way of getting grouping. If it's (for example) too large to sort conveniently, you can (for example) count items instead (total number and number of each unique item).

Comment: No,that's not the problem, string like this "ddaa" it's permutation  is 0; bcuze it's not sorting so the answer will be zero , my code get 2 ?